# Simple vector derivative using chain rule

Tags: derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

I am aware that I could factor out $\boldsymbol{v_c}$ first and then the answer is $\boldsymbol{u_1}^T + \boldsymbol{u_2}^T $. But I am doing this exercise mainly for convincing myself how chain rule works when vector is involved.

Suppose all vectors are column vectors. Here are the variables

$ J = \boldsymbol{u_1}^T \boldsymbol{v_c} + \boldsymbol{u_2}^T \boldsymbol{v_c} $

$ \theta_1 = \boldsymbol{u_1}^T \boldsymbol{v_c} $

$ \theta_2 = \boldsymbol{u_2}^T \boldsymbol{v_c} $

${\boldsymbol{\theta} = [\theta_1, \theta_2]^T}$

I would like to know answer to the following derivatives:

## 1. $\frac{\partial{J}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}$

## 2. $\frac{\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{v_c}}}$

## 3. $\frac{\partial{J}}{\partial{\boldsymbol{v_c}}}$

and I wonder if the dot product of the first two would equal the third one, according to chain rule? Or am I using chain rule correctly at all?

I am kind of confused about chain rule in the context of matrix. [Matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) reads quite overwhelming. If there is a more introductory source to this subject, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've learned enough to answer the question myself, and share my answer.

*Short answer:* Yes in the form of $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v} \frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial v}$. Otherwise, $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v} $ won't work out given these are column vectors.

*More details:*

For simplicity and clarity, I will

1. unbold symbols. Whether it's a vector or scalar should be easily inferable from the context
2. use $v$ instead of $v_c$
3. use superscript ($^{(i)}$) to indicate the $i$th element within a vector. So $\theta^{(1)}$ and $\theta^{(2)}$ are the same as $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ in the question.
4. suppose $v$ is $n$-dimensional

Actually, in Jacobian, row vector is more natural.

In terms of **row vector**:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta^T} 
&= [1, 1] \\
\\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v^T} 
&= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial \theta^{(1)}}{\partial v^{(1)}} & \cdots & \frac{\theta^{(1)}}{\partial v^{(1)}} \\ 
\frac{\partial \theta^{(2)}}{\partial v^{(1)}} & \cdots & \frac{\theta^{(2)}}{\partial v^{(n)}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \\
\\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial v^T} &= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial J}{\partial v^{(1)}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial J}{\partial v^{(n)}} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

So
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta^T} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v^T} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial v^T}
$$

Now, it's easy to transpose both sides, and see the result in terms of **column vector**.

\begin{align*}
(\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta^T} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v^T})^T &= (\frac{\partial J}{\partial v^T})^T \\
\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v} \frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta} 
&= \frac{\partial J}{\partial v}
\end{align*}
The shapes of matrices on the LHS are $(n \times 2) \cdot (2 \times 1)$.

The matrix shape on the RHS is also $(n \times 1$, so that checks out.

What I originally intended to ask in the question was effectively whether

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v_c} =? \frac{\partial J}{\partial v_c} 
$$

The answer is NO because the shapes of matrices on the LHS won't checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the $k^{th}$ column of the matrix $U$ by $u_k$.

Denote the vector, all of whose components are equal to one, by $e$.

Then you can write the quantities of interest as
$$\eqalign{
 \theta &= U^Tv_c \cr
 J &= e^T\theta \cr
}$$
and calculate their differentials
$$\eqalign{
 d\theta &= U^T\,dv_c \cr
 dJ &= e^T\,d\theta \cr &= e^TU^T\,dv_c \cr
}$$
The requested gradients are therefore
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial v_c} &= U^T \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial J}{\partial\theta} &= e^T \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial J}{\partial v_c} &= e^TU^T \cr\cr
}$$

Comment: So you are using the so-called [Numerator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions), right?

Comment: I'm not sure.  It looks to me like $$\frac{\partial J}{\partial v_c}=\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}\,\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial v_c}$$ is that considered numerator layout?

Comment: I asked because your $\frac{\partial J}{\partial \theta}$ does not have the same shape as $\theta$. I thought the derivative with respect to a vector should have the same shape as the vector itself, no?